# Binary search in array cannot find number correctly

Tags: binary-search

Binary search is not working for number 5,3 and 7 in the array when I change the target value program shows no result.

package com.company;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[] array = {8, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 1,9};

         int low=0;
         int target=4;
         int high=array.length-1;
         while (low<=high){
             int middle=low+(high-low)/2;
             int value=array[middle];
             System.out.println(middle);
             if(value<target){
                 low=middle+1;

             }
             else if(value>target)
                 high=middle-1;


             else
             {
                 System.out.println("found "+middle);
                break;
             }

         }

    }


}
```

what do I need to change in code

Comment: Please edit your tags to indicate which language this is - it could be assumed to be more than one as it stands

Answer (score 1):

The array must be sorted for binary search to work. Try adding `Arrays.sort(array);` right before the search. (Here's the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)) for that method.)